# Filter Multiple Combo Box SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to filter multiple combo box.
My code seems working if the logic: (CreatedBy1)&& (TaskStatus1) 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfZAT.png)

View:

```
    <fb:FilterBar id="filterBar" useToolbar="false" search="onPressGo">
                <fb:filterGroupItems>

                <fb:FilterGroupItem visibleInFilterBar="true" groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A8" label="Region">
                    <fb:control>
                        <MultiComboBox
                        id = "Region"
                        width = "260px"
                        items="{
                            path: '/VH_RegionSet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                            <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>   

                <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A7" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Road Master Area">
                    <fb:control>
                        <MultiComboBox
                        id = "RoadMasterAreaId"
                        width = "260px"
                        items="{
                                path: '/VH_RoadMasterAreaSet',
                                sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                                }">
                            <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>


                <fb:FilterGroupItem  groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A6" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Sub-Division/Yard Indicator">
                    <fb:control>
                        <MultiComboBox
                        id = "SubdivYardIndicator"
                        width = "260px"
                        items="{
                                path: '/VH_SubdivYardIndicatorSet',
                                sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                                }">
                            <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>


                <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A5" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Track Type">
                    <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox
                    id = "TrackType"
                    width = "260px"
                    items="{
                            path: '/VH_TrackTypeSet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                            <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>


                <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A4" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Asset Type">
                    <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox
                    id = "AssetType"
                    width = "260px"
                    items="{
                            path: '/VH_AssetTypeSet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                        <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>



                <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A3" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Created By">
                    <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox
                      id = "CreatedBy"
                      width = "260px"
                      items="{
                            path: '/VH_CreatedBySet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                        <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>

                <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A2" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Characteristic">
                    <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox
                    id = "CharacteristicId"
                    width = "260px"
                    items="{
                            path: '/VH_CharacteristicSet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                        <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>


                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" groupTitle="Group1" name="A1" visibleInFilterBar="true" label="Task Status">
                    <fb:control>
                    <MultiComboBox
                    id = "TaskStatus"
                    width = "260px"
                    items="{
                            path: '/VH_TaskStatusSet',
                            sorter: { path: 'Text' }
                            }">
                        <core:Item key="{Code}" text="{Text}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
                    </fb:control>       
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
```

Controller:

```
onPressGo: function (oEvent) {
            var oTaskFilter = [];
            var afinalFilter = [];
            var aTaskFilter = [];
            var aQuery = ["Region","RoadMasterAreaId","SubdivYardIndicator","TrackType","AssetType","CreatedBy","CharacteristicId","TaskStatus"];

        if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
            this.onRefresh();
        } 
        else {
            for(var i= 0; i< aQuery.length ; i++){
                var sQuery = this.byId(aQuery[i]).getSelectedKeys();
                    if(sQuery){
                        for(var j=0 ; j< sQuery.length ; j++){
                            oTaskFilter.push(new Filter({
                            path : aQuery[i],
                            operator : FilterOperator.EQ,
                            value1: sQuery
                        }));
                        aTaskFilter=aTaskFilter.concat(oTaskFilter);
                        }
                }
         afinalFilter=afinalFilter.concat(aTaskFilter);
        }
            this._applySearch(afinalFilter);
      }
    },
```

But I'm trying to do : (CreatedBy1) && (TaskStatus1&TaskStatus2) the screen will appear "No Matching found".
Somehow, It doesnt work if I selected more than 1 value in the same ComboBox.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtVjP.png)

Comment: The question cannot be answered with the given information. Please provide a complete snippet and an short explanation of your data model.

Comment: Hi,I have edit this issue with more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try To define `OTaskFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilters, bAnd);` with bAnd = false and put your Filters inside the filters array of this filter and then try again.

That will ensure that all your collected filters are connected with OR.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand. Why do we need to use OR? Since in my situation I need to filter out two status for 1 user.

Comment: you have to connect the two filters for the taskStatus with OR if you want to get results for both taskttatus.

Comment: I have try the suggestion. It does work out for 1 user with both taskStatus. However, when I want to filter out only for CreatedBy combo box, I choose 2 user. It does not filter. It appears No data.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way, it does filter when user1 with taskStatus1 & taskStatus2. But, it does not filter when I chose user1 & user2 only. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tahmH.png)

```
            onPressGo: function (oEvent) {
                var oTaskFilter = [];
                var afinalFilter = [];
                var aTaskFilter = [];
                var aQuery = ["Region","RoadMasterAreaId","SubdivYardIndicator","TrackType","AssetType","CreatedBy","CharacteristicId","TaskStatus"];

            if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
                this.onRefresh();
            } 
            else {
                for(var i= 0; i< aQuery.length ; i++){
                    var sQuery = this.byId(aQuery[i]).getSelectedKeys();
                        if(sQuery){

                            for(var j=0 ; j< sQuery.length ; j++){


                                oTaskFilter.push(new Filter({path : aQuery[i],
                                                            operator : FilterOperator.EQ,
                                                            value1: sQuery
                                                            })
                                                );

                            aTaskFilter.push(new Filter (oTaskFilter,false));

                            }
                    }

                    afinalFilter.push(new Filter(aTaskFilter,true));


            }
                this._applySearch(afinalFilter);
          }
        },
```